# IntelliJ Maven error: Repository is non-nexus repo, or is not indexed

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build, sonatype

[image]

Hello,

I'm getting this error for the sonatype repository. I'm pretty sure I set it up correctly in the pom.xml:

```
<repository>
    <id>OSS Sonatype</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
</repository>
```

I have already tried invalidating caches, reinstalling my entire IDE, deleting the .m2 folder or clicking every reload button I found. Nothing was successful. What is the issue here?

Note: The https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ repository did not work either.

Comment: This notification means that this repository you specify by the URL does not have an index file. So it cannot be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

I do not set up Nexus in my pom.xml.

The correct way to do it is to add a [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html) to your .m2 folder